# I need to backup views and procedures with generate scripts on sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to backup views and procedures with generate scripts on sql server

it's possible to do?

Comment: And why didn't you write them as scripts to begin with so they could be in Source Control with the rest of the code? You should NEVER make database changes using the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with SQL Server Mangement Studio. Right click on a database and select Tasks - Generate scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=56e5b1c5-bf17-42e0-a410-371a838e570a&displaylang=en) to generate scripts for tables, views, stored procedures and even data.

Comment: idk why but on 'microsoft sql server database publishing wizard' haven't views and procedures.

Comment: i can select 'schema' , 'tables' , 'Users'

Comment: maybe it's cuz i'm using sql server 2005 express?(it's not full version)

Comment: @Kokdui2, I can assure you that in the full version, you can see everything unless you don't have rights to the objects in question. Have you tried scripting the entire database and see if it scripts what you want? I never tried to script from the express version so I don;t know if it is more limited.